# Infinite Api calls on search, jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

When I press the search button it infinitely calls the api, i don't know why it is happening, I know the code is a little bit messy because i'm still learning

This is the paging source:

```
class SearchedPhotoListPagingSource(
    private val repository: PhotoRepository,
    private val query: String,
    private val orderBy: String,
    private val safeSearch: String,
    private val color: String,
    private val orientation: String
) : PagingSource<Int, PhotoDto>() {
    override fun getRefreshKey(state: PagingState<Int, PhotoDto>): Int =
        ((state.anchorPosition ?: 0) - state.config.initialLoadSize / 2)
            .coerceAtLeast(0)

    override suspend fun load(params: LoadParams<Int>): LoadResult<Int, PhotoDto> {
        val page = params.key ?: 1
        return try {
            val response = repository.getSearchedPhotos(
                page = page,
                query = query,
                orderBy = orderBy,
                safeSearch = safeSearch,
                color = color,
                orientation = orientation
            )
            val endOfPaginationReached = response.results.isEmpty()

            LoadResult.Page(
                data = response.results,
                prevKey = if (page == 1) null else page - 1,
                nextKey = if (endOfPaginationReached) null else page + 1
            )
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            LoadResult.Error(e)
        }
    }

}
```

This it the viewModel there are many fields that i am not using, currently just trying to implement the search by query only.

```
@HiltViewModel
class SearchScreenViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val repository: PhotoRepository,

) : ViewModel() {

    private var _orderBy = mutableStateOf("relevant")
    private var _safeSearch = mutableStateOf("low")
    private var _color = mutableStateOf("blue")
    private var _orientation = mutableStateOf("portrait")

    private val _searchQuery = mutableStateOf("")
    val searchQuery = _searchQuery

    fun updateSearchQuery(query: String) {
        _searchQuery.value = query
    }

    fun searchHeroes(
        query: String,
        orderBy: String,
        safeSearch: String,
        color: String,
        orientation: String
    ): Flow<PagingData<PhotoDto>> =
        Pager(
            PagingConfig(10)
        ) {
            SearchedPhotoListPagingSource(
                repository,
                query,
                orderBy,
                safeSearch,
                color,
                orientation
            )
        }.flow.cachedIn(viewModelScope)

    private val _sortingOptions = listOf(
        SelectionOption("latest", false),
        SelectionOption("relevant", false)
    ).toMutableStateList()
    val sortingOptions: List<SelectionOption>
        get() = _sortingOptions


    private val _orientationOptions = listOf(
        SelectionOption("landscape", false),
        SelectionOption("portrait", false),
        SelectionOption("squarish", false)
    ).toMutableStateList()
    val orientationOptions: List<SelectionOption>
        get() = _orientationOptions


    private val _colorOptions = listOf(
        SelectionOption("black_and_white", false),
        SelectionOption("black", false),
        SelectionOption("white", false),
        SelectionOption("yellow", false),
        SelectionOption("orange", false),
        SelectionOption("red", false),
        SelectionOption("purple", false),
        SelectionOption("magenta", false),
        SelectionOption("green", false),
        SelectionOption("teal", false),
        SelectionOption("blue", false),
    ).toMutableStateList()
    val colorOptions: List<SelectionOption>
        get() = _colorOptions


    private val _safeOptions = listOf(
        SelectionOption("low", true),
        SelectionOption("high", false)
    ).toMutableStateList()
    val safeOptions: List<SelectionOption>
        get() = _safeOptions


    fun sortingOptionSelected(selectedOption: SelectionOption) {
        _sortingOptions.forEach {
            it.selected = (it.option == selectedOption.option) && !it.selected
        }
        _orderBy.value = selectedOption.option
        Log.e("Color filter", _orderBy.value)

    }


    fun orientationOptionSelected(selectedOption: SelectionOption) {
        _orientationOptions.forEach {
            it.selected = (it.option == selectedOption.option) && !it.selected
        }
        _orientation.value = selectedOption.option
        Log.e("Color filter", _orientation.value)
    }


    fun colorOptionSelected(selectedOption: SelectionOption) {
        _colorOptions.forEach {
            it.selected = (it.option == selectedOption.option) && !it.selected
        }
        _color.value = selectedOption.option
        Log.e("Color filter", _color.value)
    }

    fun safeOptionSelected(selectedOption: SelectionOption) {
        _safeOptions.forEach { it.selected = false }
        _safeOptions.forEach {
            if (it.option == selectedOption.option) {
                it.selected = true
            }

        }
        _safeSearch.value = selectedOption.option
        Log.e("Color filter", _safeSearch.value)
    }
}
```

This is the search list composable:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalFoundationApi::class)
@Composable
fun SearchList(
    navController: NavController,
    searchQuery: String,
    viewModel: SearchScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel()
) {

    val state = viewModel.searchHeroes(
        searchQuery,
        orderBy = "latest",
        "high",
        "yellow",
        "portrait"
    ).collectAsLazyPagingItems()

    Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        Box(
            modifier = Modifier
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)
                .fillMaxSize(),
            contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
        ) {

            val lifeCycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current

            state.apply {

                LazyVerticalGrid(
                    columns = GridCells.Fixed(2),
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(7.dp),
                    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(7.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .padding(horizontal = 8.dp)
                ) {
                    item(span = { GridItemSpan(maxCurrentLineSpan) }) {
                        Spacer(modifier = Modifier.size(0.dp))
                    }

                    items(state.itemCount) { index ->

                        Row(modifier = Modifier.animateItemPlacement()) {

                            state[index]?.let { photoDto ->
                                PhotoListItem(
                                    photo = photoDto.toPhoto(),
                                    onClick = {
                                        if (state.loadState.append !is LoadState.Error) {
                                            val currentState = lifeCycleOwner.lifecycle.currentState
                                            if (currentState.isAtLeast(Lifecycle.State.RESUMED)) {
                                                navController
                                                    .navigate(Screen.PhotoDetailScreen.route + "/${it.photoId}")
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                )
                            }

                        }
                    }

                    if (state.loadState.append is LoadState.Loading) {
                        item(span = { GridItemSpan(maxCurrentLineSpan) }) {
                            ItemLoadingIndicator()
                        }
                    }

                }


                when (state.loadState.append) {

                    is LoadState.Error -> {
                        val e = (state.loadState.append as LoadState.Error).error
                        var message = ""
                        if (e is UnknownHostException) {
                            message = "No internet.\nCheck your connection"
                        } else if (e is Exception) {
                            message = e.message ?: "Unknown error occurred"
                        }

                        PhotoListItemRetry(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
                            text = message
                        ) {
                            state.retry()
                        }
                    }

                    else -> {}
                }


                when (state.loadState.refresh) {

                    is LoadState.Error -> {
                        PhotoListItemRetry(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .align(Alignment.BottomCenter),
                            text = "No internet.\n" +
                                    "Check your connection"
                        ) {
                            state.retry()
                        }

                        ErrorImage()
                    }

                    LoadState.Loading -> {
                        CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Center))
                    }

                    else -> {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This the main search screen:

```
@Composable
fun SearchScreen(
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
    viewModel: SearchScreenViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
    navController: NavController
) {
    var text by remember { mutableStateOf("") }
    var searchBarHeight by remember { mutableStateOf(0.dp) }
    var currentPageIndex by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(0) }

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            SearchBar(
                modifier = Modifier
                    .zIndex(1f)
                    .clearFocusOnKeyboardDismiss(),
                value = text,
                onValueChange = {
                    text = it
                },
                onSearch = {
                    viewModel.updateSearchQuery(text)

                    currentPageIndex = 1
                },
                paddingValue = { paddingValues ->
                    searchBarHeight = paddingValues
                }
            )
        },
        floatingActionButton = {
            FloatingActionButton(onClick = { currentPageIndex = 0 }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Rounded.Search,
                    contentDescription = "Search"
                )
            }
        }
    ) {

        Box(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(MaterialTheme.colorScheme.background)

        ) {

            Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                Spacer(modifier = Modifier.height(searchBarHeight))

                if (viewModel.searchQuery.value.isNotEmpty()) {
                    SearchList(
                        navController = navController,
                        searchQuery = viewModel.searchQuery.value
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

class SelectionOption(val option: String, private var initialSelectedValue: Boolean) {
    var selected by mutableStateOf(initialSelectedValue)
}
```

I tried various things, changed the SearchedPhotoListPagingSource but it still didn't work.